# VirtualBox VM lags after increasing the numbers of CPUs the VM has allocated to it

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a VirtualBox VM running Windows 10 on Windows 10.

My host computer specs:

```
Device name _______________
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.88 GB usable)
Device ID               ______________________________________
Product ID  ________________________
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   Pen and touch support with 10 touch points
```

My guest VM specs are:

- **RAM**: 3040MB
- **CPU**: 1 Processor
- **Execution Cap**: 100%
- **GPU Memory**: 256MB
- **3D Acceleration**: Enabled

I have VirtualBox’s Guest Additions installed in my guest OS. With these specs, it runs pretty smooth, but when I click buttons on the PC, it takes time to load. When I change the number of processors to 3, it got dramatically laggy.

[image]

How can I improve the performance of my VM?

Comment: The screenshot you posted from Windows booting is a common glitch of the emulated graphics card when switching resolutions. That is nothing unusual and has nothing to do with the power of the host or guest machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I change the # of processors to 3, it got dramatically laggy.

[Guest slows with more CPUs](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=77326#:%7E:text=Re%3A%20Adding%20more%20CPU%27s%20make%20guest%20slower%3F&text=No%2C%20you%27re%20not%20doing,more%20processors%20the%20more%20overhead.)

> No, you're not doing anything wrong, and yes, adding processors will
> make a guest go slower. There's overhead in the CPU load needed to
> keep track of instructions in a multi-processor guest, and the more
> processors the more overhead.

Host machine (i5 8GB) is just adequate, so Guest machines will not be speedy.

Try using 2GB for the Guest machine as a test.

Check the speed of your host hard drive.  5400-rpm will be very slow for virtual machine use. A 7200-rpm drive is workable (my X230 has a 7200-rpm drive). A fast SSD will work well. My production Thinkpad has a fast drive.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment [elsewhere](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=96265&start=0#p467017), VirtualBox expert "mpack" writes:

In real life, a lot of operations are disk-bound or network-bound.  Only a minority of operations are CPU-bound.

The more cores you create for your VM, the more overhead these cores will cause (due to context switches).

In practice, the ideal choice is usually to assign **two cores** to each VM.

If you need to run CPU-intensive tasks all day, such as video encoding, don't run these tasks in a VM.  Run them on the host OS:  they'll run faster there.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the appropriate storage driver is used. AFAIK virtio drivers are not included in virtualbox extensions for windows yet, so you should install them separately, by mounting the iso from Fedora project.
Then you will be able to switch the "controller" providing your existing virtual harddrive from  SATA to Virtual I/O Device SCSI.

Windows 10/11 really cares about two things, storage speed, and available RAM (at least up to 8GB).

So, for your case I would use the following specifications:
**RAM: 4096MB**
(Running desktop distributions of Windows 10 on under 4GB of ram is qualitatively different (literally triggers some different code paths) than running it on 4 or more. It's practically in "survival mode", which makes it rely on other resources liek CPU and storage more instead of having things cached.)

**vCores: 2**
(Otherwise you are starving your host system, which has to keep the virtual devices of the VM fed as well, which one core will definitely not be enough for, especially when it's competing with all of the other process on the host OS)