# Make Virtual Box Faster on a 4-core laptop

Tags: virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, cpu

This is a follow-up on [this earlier question I posted](https://superuser.com/questions/1642966/virtualbox-vm-lags-after-increasing-cpu).

While the comments and answers provided clarified why increasing CPUs made my VM slower, is there anything I can do to make my VM faster with these specs (like change a setting, etc.)?

```
Device name _______________
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.88 GB usable)
Device ID               ______________________________________
Product ID  ________________________
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   Pen and touch support with 10 touch points
```

Comment: The main thing I have done to make Virtual Machines faster is to use a very fast SSD main disk. This helps enormously and also the suggestion by LPChip to use 16 GB of memory. I have that as well.

Comment: Good point @John I'll add that to the answer as well.

Comment: There's really very little if anything to say beyond what was already said. It seems you're looking for a "magical incantation" but there is none outside of fiction. A crucial spec is still missing here as I alluded in the other answer: The drive where the VM is, HDD or SSD?

Comment: I have a solid state drive

Answer (score 2):

The specs for your laptop aren't too great, so you can't really get much performance. Want more speed, upgrade or replace the laptop.

8 GB ram means you can only use 4GB RAM for both the Host OS and 4GB Ram for the guest. 4GB ram to run windows 10 just isn't enough.

It works but it will be slow. 16GB is recommended, so you can assign 8GB RAM to the guest. That'll make a huge difference.

Another part that you can upgrade for a bit of a speed increase is making sure you have an SSD that the VM and the host have their files on. SSD storage is not that expensive anymore and will make a difference, though RAM will make a bigger difference for sure, but if possible, upgrade both or the entire laptop.

Next, give the guest 2 CPU cores.

If you really want to have the best performance ever, don't use VirtualBox. Setup dual boot and have one environment for what you'd do in the virtual environment and the other for daily use, or if you really want a virtual setup so you can run both, run Linux as your host.